# PL SQL - Lazy Caterer's Sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a  PL/SQL program to print out the first 10 numbers of Lazy Caterer's sequence.  I'm having trouble. I don't understand how to do this
Lazy caterer's sequence has the formula `F(1)=2, F(n)=F(n-1)+n`. 
E.g., `F(2) = F(1) + 2 = 2+2=4;  F(3) = F(2)+3 = 4+3=7`

Please use a loop. The numbers you print out should look like

```
2
4
7
...
56
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE
    n NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        n := n + i;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I cheated and looked up [Lazy Caterer's algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence). This is an implementation of the simplistic version of the formula:

```
create or replace function lc_algo 
    (n in number)
    return number as
begin
    return (power(n,2) + n + 2) / 2;
end;
/
```

I admit it doesn't use a loop, but it's hard to see why anybody would need to. However, if your assignment insists on loops (because performance is not your bag) here you go:

```
create or replace function lc_algo 
    (n in number)
    return number 
as
    rv simple_integer := 1;
begin
    for i in 1..n loop
        rv := rv + i;
    end loop;
    return rv;
end;
/
```

To get the first ten numbers (with whatever version):

```
select lc_algo(level) -- assuming you don't want to start with f(0)
from dual
connect by level <= 10
/
```